# TACO will not remote build ios with the --device parameter specified

Tags: ios, cordova, command-line, cordova-cli, taco

Remotebuild is up and running on my osx server, and I can build with :

```
taco build ios
```

But when I try the following

```
taco build ios --device
```

I get a big old error

```
------ Incremental Build: true
------ Submitting new build request to: http://xxx.xxx.net:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.1.1&vcli=0.8.0&cfg=debug&platform=ios&options=--device%20undefined&buildNumber=20057
------ 1:55:14 PM Checking on build status from http://xxx.xxx.net:3000/cordova/build/tasks/20057 [Attempt 1]
Uploaded - Uploaded build request payload.
Remote build log written to C:\work\helltaco\remote\ios\debug\build.log
------ 1:55:19 PM Checking on build status from http://xxx.xxx.net:3000/cordova/build/tasks/20057 [Attempt 2]
Error - Build failed with error Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun -v -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication platforms/ios/build/device/io.taco.hellotaco.app -o /Users/xxx/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/20057/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/HelloTaco.ipa
xcrun: note: PATH = '/Users/xxx/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/1.0.1/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin'
xcrun: note: SDKROOT = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk'
xcrun: note: TOOLCHAINS = ''
xcrun: note: DEVELOPER_DIR = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'
xcrun: note: XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH = ''
xcrun: note: xcrun_db = '/var/folders/s8/9typ1pdj1lg88n7r9wg5f9rc0000gn/T/xcrun_db'
xcrun: note: xcrun via PackageApplication (xcrun)
xcrun: note: database key is: PackageApplication|/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk||/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer|
xcrun: note: lookup resolved in '/var/folders/s8/9typ1pdj1lg88n7r9wg5f9rc0000gn/T/xcrun_db' : '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication'
error: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/io.taco.hellotaco.app'

TACO5629: Remote build failed
Inner Error:
Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun -v -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication platforms/ios/build/device/io.taco.hellotaco.app -o /Users/xxx/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/20057/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/HelloTaco.ipa
xcrun: note: PATH = '/Users/xxx/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/1.0.1/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin'
xcrun: note: SDKROOT = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk'
xcrun: note: TOOLCHAINS = ''
xcrun: note: DEVELOPER_DIR = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'
xcrun: note: XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH = ''
xcrun: note: xcrun_db = '/var/folders/s8/9typ1pdj1lg88n7r9wg5f9rc0000gn/T/xcrun_db'
xcrun: note: xcrun via PackageApplication (xcrun)
xcrun: note: database key is: PackageApplication|/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk||/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer|
xcrun: note: lookup resolved in '/var/folders/s8/9typ1pdj1lg88n7r9wg5f9rc0000gn/T/xcrun_db' : '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication'
error: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/io.taco.hellotaco.app'
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've kinda hit a brickwall here :(

Comment: Hey Adam, Thanks for reporting this issue and using TACO. We are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for using TACO and reporting this issue. Its a legitimate bug where we incorrectly parse the "--device" option, causing the remote build not to honor this parameter and fail as you have described.

While we are actively fixing it and though you cannot build your application for a device, you can always run your application on an emulator from taco by just running "taco emulate ios" to run your application on the ios simulator.

If you need an IPA, here is a workaround, but it would need you to modify a JS file within our package. This would build the IPA and bring it back on your windows machine at \remote\ios\debug.

The workaround is changing ***line 370*** of %appdata%\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\cli\remoteBuild\remoteBuildClientHelper.js from:

```
params["options"] = "--device " + params["options"];
```

to:

```
params["options"] = "--device";
```

**Note**: The removal of whitespace after **--device** is important.

Let me know if you have any questions or concerns & once again thanks for using TACO. We are getting ready for the 1.0.0 release of TACO which is going to happen soon and it should have this issue fixed!

Thanks, 
SOak.

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. Getting an IPA out now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can confirm this now properly works (tested on 1.2.0). Deploys to my device without issues. Thank you Taco :D.